# Intuition for the supertrace identity in supersymmetry

Tags: quantum-spin, supersymmetry, representation-theory, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

In pretty much every introductory book/lecture notes I've come across, one finds the expression for the mass matrices for scalars, fermions and vector bosons for a generic Lagrangian, and simply observes directly that the supertrace, defined by
$$STr(M) = \sum_s (-1)^{2s}(2s+1)Tr(M_s^2)$$
vanishes (up to possible anomalies). Here $M$ is the total mass matrix of the Lagrangian, and $M_s$ are the mass matrices for the spin $s$ particles.

I've also seen [in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertrace) that this is actually a general theorem for superalgebras.

But can this be shown to be true using simple arguments such as symmetry or basic SUSY properties, and not just via technical manipulations or abstract mathematics?

It seems too fundamental to be just a clever observation, so I'm really looking for some insight for this result. For example, I have a feeling that this is somehow related to the mass degeneracy that is built in to SUSY, but I don't know if this is enough to obtain such a result or even if this is at all true.

Answer (score 2):

1. OP's formula originates from the definition of supertrace $${\rm str}(M)~=~{\rm tr}(A) -{\rm tr}(D)  \tag{1}$$ of an even $(n|m)\times(n|m)$ [supermatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermatrix) 
   $$M~=~\begin{pmatrix} A & B \cr C & D \end{pmatrix},\tag{2}$$
   here written in its Grassmann-even and  Grassmann-odd decomposition.
2. Definition (1) is uniquely determined by the requirements that

   - the supertrace should be linear.
   - the supertrace of a supercommutator $[M,N]$ of two square supermatrices $M$ & $N$ should vanish.
   - the supertrace should reduce to the ordinary trace for Grassmann-even matrices.

Comment: This explains why the supertrace is defined as it is, but I think the heart of OP's issue is why it vanishes in many situations.